# Why: put on hold as unclear what you're asking

Tags: discussion, specific-question, question-quality

In my opinion, the below question was researched and thought out.

The questions are directly stipulated.

So why is it that it is *put on hold as unclear what you're asking*?

[Datum, Value, Value Type, Object and Object Type in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50513561/datum-value-value-type-object-and-object-type-in-c)

Comment: Well Too Broad would be appropriate given that you're asking a while bunch of questions, assuming people understood all of them.

Comment: I'm not sure about unclear, so I can't explain that, but it _is_ asking multiple questions, so it definitely looks "too broad" to me.

Comment: The 3 questions are related.

Comment: _Related,_ sure, but they look like questions that, while related, could certainly be asked without asking the other questions. Indeed, the answer posted lists them out as separate questions as well, and separate answers. So, it looks like this should have been separated into three questions, not one.

Comment: Yeah, trying to get a *k*-fer on your question would warrant a "too broad" vote in most cases.  In this scenario most people just couldn't understand what they were asking in the midst of all of those questions.

Comment: "question was researched, and thought out." A question can be researched and though out and not clear.  "The questions are directly stipulated."  That they asked the questions directly doesn't mean people understood them.

Comment: @Servy:  Doesn't look like *this* OP and *that* OP are the same.

Comment: It's not my question.

Comment: So if people don't understand the question, shouldn't they "skip" the review?

Comment: **Yes.  If you don't understand what's going on, you can't succinctly review it.  Skipping is _fine_ in that context.**

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk If they feel like they aren't qualified to judge if the question is going to be understandable to subject matter experts in that area, they should skip it.  If they feel confident that the question does not have enough information to be understood by people familiar with the material, they should close it.

Comment: That is a very rough question.  I think the OP's true intention is only revealed in his last comment, he's looking for a mapping for the book's terminology to words he is familiar with.  Which of course does beg the question what *exactly* he is familiar with.  Goes horribly wrong in the first bullet, no less, it is all three.  A book like that can be pretty useful, but you do have to buy into the brain transplant.  Reading it, oh, four times is necessary.

Comment: @HansPassant In my opinion this person is on the verge of understanding the difference between lvalues and rvalues - they just don't understand this terminology yet. Do I understand correctly that because this question delves into understanding the theory and background of the language it is not good for SO?

Comment: [tag:C++]. Run. Far and fast.

Comment: @Will Of course! If you don't understand, you will get burnt. But the question is a general kind which is common to many languages,

Answer (score 7):

The question is basically, "here are a bunch of arbitrary definitions of terms. How do these fit into a system that has completely different definitions for some of those terms?" It's a question founded in misunderstanding: the idea that the definitions in "From Mathematics to Generic Programming" have anything to do with the definitions in "The Standard for Programming Language C++".

While I would have gone for "too broad", "unclear" is entirely appropriate, since I have no idea what the OP is expecting from an answer. And this is from someone who understands the C++ object model.