# How should this question have been handled?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

Someone who appears to be new to programming and/or C++ posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50516941/9614249) asking about how the purpose of 4 different logical operators in a small snippet of code.

The comments immediately start pointing out errors in the question

- OP does not understand the difference between declaration and definition
- OP didn't include information about the `float2` (although has no relevance to the question being asked)
- OP used more brackets than necessary

These are all helpful things to point out to a beginner, but instead we have

- High rep users with years of C++ experiencing pretending they cannot understand what the question is asking because the question uses the word declaration instead of definition
- A suggestion to read the first 10 pages of any C++ book
- Multiple people talking about the OP as if he or she is not present

None of these things are constructive

And finally the question was closed as Too Broad with the advice:

> Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The question already had an [adequate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50517014/9614249) posted prior to being put on hold. It is obvious what the OP is asking no amount of editing will suddenly make the question significantly more clear.

The only reasoning I can come up with for this question being marked as Too Broad is the fact that the question asks about 4 different operators and so it could be considered 4 different questions. However, given the scope of what OP is asking could easily fit into a single answer I don't think this question should be classified as Too Broad. [This Meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259857/9614249) and the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) both seem to back up this reasoning. There is most certainly one single correct answer to this question and it fits concisely in a single answer.

I'm not sure what the correct action for this question is, but the way it was handled definitely seems less than ideal.

Should the question have been marked as a duplicate? Is it unique enough on its own? If it is too broad, what could be changed to improve the question?

Comment: Too broad looks appropriate as he/she is asking multiple questions and is truly asking about the very basic rudiments of the language, things that can and *should* be looked up in a tutorial or text book. This site makes a very poor substitute for doing these actions.

Comment: Coin toss, heads for 'Unclear', tails for 'Too broad'.

Comment: @MartinJames [And both are losing moves](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368546/why-put-on-hold-as-unclear-what-youre-asking).

Comment: @Servy well, with Kobayashi Maru questions, may as well get the defeat oiver with quickly.  The coin toss gets round wasting time trying to decie bwtween unclear [why the dozens of textbooks and online tutorials do not cover your issue] and too broad [because explaining all those operators would take pages of duplicate giunge].  Toss, vote, move on to good question, (optimistically:).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I'm going to take personal umbrage to this statement:

> High rep users with years of C++ experiencing pretending they cannot understand what the question is asking because the question uses the word declaration instead of definition

Declaration and definition are two distinct words and have *very* distinct meanings.  An expert has the right - or obligation - to ask for a clarification, and consider the question "confusing" until one is provided.

So I'm not going to largely disagree with your remark about the comments; those aren't entirely necessary or relevant to the question.  Those are some prime examples of users being unnecessarily curt; you don't need to give the advice of "go read a book", since any casual observer will think that we're just being jerks.  Again.

However, I *still* feel like the question should be closed based on [a recurring theme](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367894/1079354) [of mine as of late](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367178/1079354):

## Are we here to teach, or are we here to help?

The OP here was looking for someone to *teach* them C++ operators.  That's ***not*** the role we fill in here.  Any answer to the solution would still feel too broad as to not encompass everything.  While I admit that the answer that's there does a decent job of conveying all of the parts, I don't see it *not* leading into additional questions or chatter in the comments.  By and large, that's how these questions have turned out.

Comment: I largely agree with your points and do think the question should be closed, but in this particular question is it *really* unclear which lines the user is asking about? It is possible they forgot to include a declaration with the operators in question, but it seems overwhelmingly likely that the new user who is struggling with basic concepts made the incredibly common mistake among beginners of confusing the two terms and intended to refer to the only two lines in the question that contain the symbols in question.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic:  I'd consider it a case of "I wouldn't overturn the close vote."   Giving you the benefit of the doubt, it *might* be that the question isn't all that unclear, but again, I don't see much in the way to reopen the question based on the points prior.

Answer (score 2):

You think it's obvious what the OP does and doesn't understand, and what actually needs to be explained to them.  Someone else thinks that it's *obviously* some entirely different aspect of the snippet that they don't understand and need explained.

There are *all sorts* of things that one might not understand in the snippet, and any number of things that they might understand that you might not expect them to have understood.

We don't want everyone all trying to just *guess* what the OP does or doesn't understand, and all posting their own wildly different answers accordingly.  They need to clarify what they do understand, what they don't understand, and what about it is confusing to them, so that *the specific aspect that they don't understand* can be explained.

> Should the question have been marked as a duplicate?

When the OP clarifies what, specifically, they don't understand, almost certainly.  This was even said in the comments.  Basically any one aspect of that snippet is going to be explained in a duplicate, but you can't very well close the question as a duplicate of dozens of different questions each explaining different aspects of it.

Comment: "*When the OP clarifies what, specifically, they don't understand*". But we do know what the OP doesn't understand. The question asks "*What is the purpose of `==`, `||`, `?` and `:` in the declaration?*". If the problem is that too many things are asked in one question, would it be acceptable for the OP to have posted 4 different questions asking about each operator?

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic What don't they understand about each of those operators?  And of course there are lots of questions about all of those operators.  Whatever they want to know about them is almost certainly a duplicate.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic When someone doesn't understand the most basic concepts like operator `==`, `||`, the only thing acceptable is to read a book and learn those basic stuff *by themselves*. They should not go to a programmer site to post questions.

Comment: @liliscent - and explaining those operators should cover the half-dozen overloads that the OP forgot to mention:)